# Windows 10 pc keeps shutting down when I hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, shutdown, hibernate

I recently got a new PC. As I always do, I wiped the SSD & reinstalled windows 10 from scratch.

Since installing v1903 it has randomly started shutting down when I hibernate - whether through the option in the power menu or the power button. This could be something to do with v1903, but I don't know that, and can't roll it back to an earlier version because I run several apps for work that require v1903. I have run the power troubleshooter, which turned up nothing.

I am running a dell latitiude E7440 with 16gb of ram, a 256gb SSD, an intel i7 and windows 10 pro.

Can anybody help me fix this problem?

Comment: have you correctly updated all the drivers ??Randomly shutting down ?? are you saying that it does hibernate sometimes ?

Comment: Yes, but not other times.

Comment: Update your BIOS

Comment: I'll see if there's an update. Good idea though. Why I didn't think of it...

Comment: good to update but I don't think that will solve anything because you said that it does hibernate sometimes...its a weird issue...are you using a touch screen ...then maybe there might be any screen touch calibration issues.

Comment: No... I think I may have just spotted a pattern... Will say more when sure

Comment: right click on battery icon > Power settings>  on the left side - "Choose what the power button does" > have you set it to hibernate there ??

Comment: Yes, I have done that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/my-computer-shuts-down-instead-of-hibernating-or/5fe1e2ae-3883-41c3-980f-e0009409dd29) you could try running "Power troubleshooter", it should fix all power relatied option (instructions to do that are int he link). If that however doesn't solve your problem, try turning of "Hybrid sleep", as instructed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/laptop-shuts-down-instead-of-hibernate-after/0838a3f2-8313-4d06-828d-35df74b49f40).

Comment: Tried both of those options. The one for hybrid sleep doesn't even appear.